# If Else only choosing first option

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to set up an **If Else** statement which decides which MYSQL query to use depending on the values submitted in a form.

The problem I am having is that no matter which values I send in the form, even if they are not `ALL`, only the first query gets called ever.

Here is my code:

```
 if($department = 'ALL' && $property_type = 'ALL')

 } elseif ($department = 'ALL'){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` to compare not `=`.

`=` is an **assignment operator**.

`==` and `===` are **comparative operators**.

Comment: I can't believe i missed that, thank you

Comment: @RecruitTechnology glad I could help.